# Can ProgressBar spin while main thread is sleeping?

Tags: android

While debugging some weird behaviour of my app, I noticed that a `ProgressBar` is spinning while I'm doing something on the main thread, for example `Thread.sleep(10000)`. I assumed that the spinning or anything UI related always happens on the main thread. Is this normal?

Comment: Yup, there is another thread for animations, I think its called `RenderThread`. Btw, why are you blocking mainthread for 10s?

Comment: I don't think this is normal , I tries a sample app and the progressbar won't even show for 10 sec

Comment: @egoldx yeah, problem solved. I'm blocking it to test that the anim really doesn't stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Lollipop android has a different thread for animations

> A new system-managed processing thread called RenderThread keeps animations smooth even when there are delays in the main UI thread.

It is used just for reasons you mentioned, as when the programmer blocks the UI thread.

Nevertheless, don't block the UI thread :)